как написать такую программу без использования Convert.ToDouble на С#?

Здравствуйте,вот условие: мне нужно разработать программу на языке C# вычисления по приведенной формуле F(x) и вывести на экран результат в указанном формате. Исходные данные вводятся с клавиатуры. Сравнить полученное значение с указанным правильным результатом.
Мой вопрос: подскажите пожалйста как мне написать код, на каком сайте найти полезный материал чтобы понять как написать данную программму
видел такой код:
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Ввод значений x и a с клавиатуры
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x:");
        double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение a:");
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        // Эталонное значение F для сравнения
        double expectedF = 10.736
        // Вычисление F по формуле
        double part1 = Math.Exp(-2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + 1.2));
        double part2 = 13 * Math.Pow(x, 1.5);
        double part3 = Math.Pow(x * a, 1 / a);
        double part4 = Math.Log(Math.Abs(Math.Tan(x / 2)));

        double F = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4;

        // Вывод результата
        Console.WriteLine($"Результат вычисления F(x): {F}");

        // Сравнение с эталонным значением
        if (Math.Abs(F - expectedF) < 1e-6) // Допустимая погрешность
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Результат совпадает с эталонным значением.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Результат отличается от эталонного значения.");
        }
    }
}

Но для меня он сложный можно ли как-то это написать не используя метод конверт,парс и т.д вообще без этих методов?
С учетом всех рекомендций решил убрать сравнение результата с эталонным значением.Ведь на моем фото проверка с неверными значениями
мой итоговый результат :
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Ввод значений x и a с клавиатуры
        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x:");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите значение a:");
        double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Вычисление F по формуле
        double part1 = Math.Exp(-2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + 1.2));
        double part2 = 13 * Math.Pow(x, 1.5);
        double part3 = Math.Pow(x * a, 1 / a);
        double part4 = Math.Log(Math.Abs(Math.Tan(x / 2)));

        double F = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4;

        // Вывод результата
        Console.WriteLine($"Результат вычисления F(x): {F}");
    }
}

это пример кода


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

возможно ли как-то совсем простым способом написать чтобы работал без каких либо методов?

Здесь и так всё крайне просто, почитайте учебник по сишарпу

@andreymal подскажите а какой учебник?

"возможно" - нет. Используются следующие методы: Main, ToDouble, ReadLine, Exp, Sqrt, Pow, Log, Abs, Tan, WriteLine. Чем вам особенно неприятен метод ToDouble?

Кстати, double expectedF = 1.0736 * Math.Pow(10, -1) записывается как double expectedF = 10.736.

@rotabor преподаватель очень сильно много вопросов задает по этому методу ему он не нравится,я уже писал программу с использованием этого метода вроде все просто , но у препода появляются сверх сложные вопросы и в следствии чего я не могу ответить я дополнил свой вопрос на данном сайте как преподаватель пишет код

@rotabor понял, учту спасибо

"ему он не нравится" - этот метод просто преобразует string в double, вот и всё. Что ему собственно в нём не нравится?

А вы хоть представляете, что делает этот метод? Без него, конечно, можно обойтись, но это будет не ваш уровень. Вопросов будет ещё больше. Так что придётся разобраться с ToDouble.

"а какой учебник?" - кликните на метке "c#", а там на ссылке "Подробнее...".

У меня было Double celsius=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Мне сказали что лучше писать double Celsius;
Celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); наверно тут мне тоже стоит исправить

@rotabor увидел книги спасибо

@rotabor ну сделайте хотя бы Console.WriteLine(1.0736 * Math.Pow(10, -1)); в любом онлайн-компиляторе

Впрочем, всё равно старый код не соответствовал числу на скриншоте ¯\(ツ)/¯

@andreymal если вы про пример кода преподавателя,да это другое ,а если вы имеете в виду про проверку, то да нам сказали во всех этих заданиях ошибки и не нужно переживать если не сходится

@andreymal А я как раз на картинку и смотрел, а минус как-то выпал из поля зрения.

Я бы заменил "Результат совпадает с эталонным значением" на "Результат в пределах допустимой погрешности".

Convert.ToDouble - вообще метод с сомнительной полезностью. Единственный случай, когда его надо использовать - это если переменная имеет тип object и ты хочешь чтобы она привелась в double потенциально с конвертацией типа. В остальных случаях есть приведение типа (double)x и парсинг строки double.Parse(s). Очевидно, что в твоём случае нужно второе.

получается вот так? // Ввод значений x и a с клавиатуры
Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x:");
double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Введите значение a:");
    double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


или лучше  double x;                                                                                                                                           х = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); как вы считаете?

@FreeDkdodo, первое.

В итоге я исправил код и убрал сравнение результата с эталонным значением.Ведь на моем фото проверка с неверными значениями можно ли так сделать или все таки нужно следовать требованиям задания? но в самом задании вроде же не сказанонно сделать сравнение результата с эталонным значением написано только : "Сравнить полученное значение с указанным правильным результатом" я так понимаю это значит просто самому ввести значения x и  a и посмотреть что выдаст

а почему 2 вариант является не желательным?

или лучше мне все таки вернуть сравнение полученного значение с указанным правильным результатом?

Я бы не хаял так "Convert.ToDouble" - Reference Source .NET Framework 4.8 Class: Convert, строка 1600. Попробуйте догадаться, что там.

@rotabor да у меня два предупреждения висят ,но я думаю это не так критично и можно добавить проверку на  null и тогда их не будет, но я думаю это преподу не понравится, т.к как он выразился если бы мы были на математике то решали 2+2 а проверку на null мы пока не проходили

а как я понимаю в конверт эта проверка уже есть как бы внутри него и лишние строки следовательно не нужно писать я имею ввиду как в методе парс тут нужно проверку на null делать,но у меня однодневная программа поэтому мне кажется это тут не обязательно

а еще можно использовать метод  double.TryParse(), который не выбрасывает исключение, если ввод некорректен

@rotabor, ну т. е. это лишняя прослойка, которая делает код менее понятным при чтении. С double.Parse я сразу понимаю, что тут парсят строку, а с Convert.ToDouble есть куча вариантов, что там может быть. В чём плюсы?

Мне ваш ответ не был сразу понятен. Поизучав, я бы мог обобщить это так: если посмотреть на реализацию, то Convert.ToDouble - это просто лишний вызов метода. Существует всего пять случаев преобразования в double: 1) большинство числовых типов преобразуются неявно (double = int); 2) decimal нужно преобразовывать явно ((double)decimal): 3) object преобразуется через приведение к iConvertible (((IConvertible)value).ToDouble(provider?)); 4) DateTime не преобразуется; 5) string преобразуется с помощью double.Parse/TryParse.

@rotabor, 4 - DateTime тоже преобразуется, вроде: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1618.

Там не всё так просто
